# Data inserting in between the rows in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table which has around 1,000,000 records. I noticed that when I insert a record it does not get inserted at last instead it gets inserted in between

Example

My table (testing)

| Si. | Name. | Address. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Test. | 1/2 test |
| 2. | Test. | 3/4 test |

Si has a unique index created but no primary keys defined

So when I make an insert into table

```
Insert into testing (si,name,address) Values (3., Test., 5/6 test)
```

I get the below

| Si. | Name. | Address. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Test. | 1/2 test |
| 3. | Test. | 5/6 test |
| 2. | Test. | 3/4 test |

How do I fix this issue.

What I know is that the value will normally get inserted at the last but this alone does this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "problem" isn't a problem at all.

This is a relational database we're talking about. Imagine it as a basket full of apples. When you put a new apple into it, how will you know which one of them was *inserted* before this one? You can't.

The same goes with inserts into a relational database table - row can be inserted *anywhere*.

If you want to return rows in certain order, you **must** use the `ORDER BY` clause. And, of course, have something to sort data by. In your example, that's the `si` column.

Therefore, instead of

```
select * from testing;
```

you'd

```
select * from testing order by si;
```

That's how it works; there's nothing you can do about it. *Sometimes* it'll look as if you can omit `order by`, but that's misleading and you can't rely on it. Always use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice explanation. i did do some research myself on this issue and found the same answer. So now its confirmed that ORDER BY is must